# Application for only specific iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, review, uidevice

Is is possible to write an iOS application available for only one or some specific Apple devices? If yes, is it risky and can be rejected by App Store Review? I can check if the device is something but I want my app to unavailable to other devices on App Store.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to target specific models, so that the app will be available only to those machines. How that affects the review process, I have no idea.